# Change required field form when option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form like below

```
       <form>
        <div class="6 op" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">Service</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                 <option></option>
                 <option>Fiber</option>
                 <option>Hotspot</option>
              </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Capacity</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="example: 1" required>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                 <option>Mbps</option>
                 <option>Gbps</option>
              </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Notes</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
           </div>
           <input type="submit">
        </div>
     </form>
```

In the code above, `required` is in `service` and `capacity`. I want to know how to add `required` to `notes` field automatically only when I choose `Hotspot` option in `service` field.

Do you know how to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: First , you should not use the same ID for elements :) [ dont copy] ;) / Second , you can use  element.change(function(){} on <select> and in body change properties to required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `onchange` event handler to select option and as a param pass the value of the selected option. In this case when the value is hotspot you can use `setAttribute` to add the attribute `required` to the textarea else set it to false or remove it using `removeAttribute`. Also id of dom elements need to be unique

```js
let txtArea = document.getElementById('exampleFormControlTextarea1');

function changeService(val) {
  if (val.toLowerCase() === 'hotspot') {
    txtArea.setAttribute('required', true)

  } else {
    txtArea.setAttribute('required', false)

  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="6 op" style="">
    <div class="form-group"><label for='exampleFormControlSelect1'>Service</label>
      <select onchange='changeService(this.value)' class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
        <option></option>
        <option>Fiber</option>
        <option>Hotspot</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput2">Capacity</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="example: 1" required>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" required>
        <option>Mbps</option>
        <option>Gbps</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Notes</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple example below , 
using jquery , if someone select specific role , code toggle class and toggle REQUIRED properties on chosen element

```
$('select#role').change(function(){
    let role = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    if (role == 0 ){
      $('.detailed').removeClass("detailed");
      $('#employee').prop('required',true);
    }
    else{
      $('#staff').addClass("detailed");
      $('#employee').prop('required',false);
    }
}); // close $('select#role').change(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jQuery. You need to set the field to required on the onChange event of dropdown.

```js
   // Perform some code on the change event of a dropdown
    $("#exampleFormControlSelect1").change(function () { 
    var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    // Get selected value and save it in selected variable
     console.log(selected);
       if(selected == "Fiber"){
          //check the selected value and set the field to required
          console.log('i am here');
          // Set capacity input to required if value if Fiber        
         // $("#capacity").attr('required',true);
// Set Notes field to required if value if Fiber
$("#exampleFormControlTextarea1").attr('required',true);
       }
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
            <div class="6 op">
            <div class="form-group">Service</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                     <option></option>
                     <option>Fiber</option>
                     <option>Hotspot</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Capacity</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="capacity" placeholder="example: 1">
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                     <option>Mbps</option>
                     <option>Gbps</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Notes</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
               </div>
               <input type="submit">
            </div>
         </form>
```

In the above example, the Notes field will become required, if you select Fiber in Service Dropdown.

Comment: the question asked to add required on `notes` not in `capacity` xD

Comment: You can do the same with capacity. Simply change the element id in JS/jQuery to get the desired results.

Comment: Anyways, i have updated the answer, you can check it now

Answer (score 0):

```js
let el = document.querySelector("#exampleFormControlSelect1");



el.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{

  if(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value == "Hotspot" ) {
  document.querySelector("#exampleFormControlTextarea1").setAttribute("required","");
} else {

document.querySelector("#exampleFormControlTextarea1").removeAttribute("required");
}

});
```

```html
       <form>
        <div class="6 op" style="">
        <div class="form-group">Service</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                 <option></option>
                 <option>Fiber</option>
                 <option>Hotspot</option>
              </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Capacity</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="example: 1" required>
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
                 <option>Mbps</option>
                 <option>Gbps</option>
              </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Notes</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
           </div>
           <input type="submit">
        </div>
     </form>
```

First of all, remove the display:none property from first div. Then check the codes above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#serviceToggle').on('change', function () {
  var data = $(this).val();
  if (data == 'hotspot') {
    $('#notes').prop('required', true);
  } else {
    $('#notes').prop('required', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="serviceToggle">Service</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="serviceToggle" required>
       <option></option>
       <option value="fiber">Fiber</option>
       <option value="hotspot">Hotspot</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Capacity</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="example: 1">
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
         <option>Mbps</option>
         <option>Gbps</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="notes">Notes</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="notes" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```